# QVector inside QML/Javascript

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

How Can I Use `QVector` inside QML/Javascript?
Example:

C++:

Custom class I use in QML. The class is including function that return `QVector` of registered `ElementType`

```cpp
class CustomType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Q_INVOKABLE QVector<ElementType*> getElements(); 
    //.....            
}
//.........
qmlRegisterType<CustomType>("CustomComponents", 1, 0, "CustomType");
qmlRegisterType<ElementType>("CustomComponents", 1, 0, "ElementType");
qRegisterMetaType<ElementType*>("ElementType*");
```

QML:

QML code receives instance of `CustomType` class (custom) and try to get `QVector<ElementType*>` of elements and reads its properties. But QML can't recognize `QVector` type.

```
//.......
function(){
    var elements = custom.getElements()
    elements[0].property   //?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QML-accessible list properties need to be constructed with `QDeclarativeListProperty`. This applies to everything that's list-shaped, also vectors. [This part of the Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-tutorials-extending-chapter5-listproperties.html) has the details.

Comment: This is not exectly what I need.
I added:
qRegisterMetaType<QVector<ElementType*> >("QVector<ElementType*>");
In QML I receive this type: QVariant(QVector<ElementType*>)
So how can I access inside QVariant?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this years late, But, here goes. This is a simple problem to resolve. Just use a Qt QVariantList type in your C++ code instead of QVector. Qt's QVariantList is essentially a QVector containing QVariant elements. And QVariants can be damn near anything once you know what you are doing. Also, QML automatically converts a C++ QVariant to its QML equivalent. Hence, if you do this in main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Prepare to enter the QML GUI world
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Create a QVariantList to be used instead of a QVector
    QVariantList dataList;
    dataList << "Item 1";
    dataList << 2;
    dataList << 3.3;

    // Create QML UI
    QQuickView view;

    // make your QVariantList visible to QML
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel",
                             QVariant::fromValue(dataList));

    // show QML UI
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return 1;

} // main()
```

You can then do this in your main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Item
{
    // Print contents of C++ QVariantList to console
    function printMeBruh()
    {
        console.log("modelData contains:")
        console.log("-------------------")

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            console.log(myModel[i])
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: printMeBruh()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you just need to return `QList` of `QObject*` from a `Q_INVOKABLE` function. Note, that all objects returned that way will have JavaScript ownership and will be garbage collected when your JavaScript function returns. To prevent this behavior use [setObjectOwnership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeengine.html#setObjectOwnership) before pushing objects into your `QList` collection.
For more information about using collections in QML see [QML Data Models](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativemodels.html)

Comment: QList is good for ListModel, but in my case I receive element of type QVariant(QList<ElementType*>) and I can't access to  the inner type of QList<ElementType*>

Comment: Don't you try to inherit from QObjectList and to add some accessor method with index argument in your own class?